# Add "locked" to the "Advanced Search Tips" menu

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search, locked-posts

Here is the "Advanced Search Tips" menu:

---

[image]

---

At the time of writing, it doesn't list how to search for locked questions. And yes, we all know we can search for locked questions:

```
locked:yes
locked:no
```

So I propose we add "locked" to the "Advanced Search Tips" menu.

Comment: `code:` is probably more useful and it isn't.

Comment: Most users searching won't know what "locked" means, I'm sure. The options more likely to be used by every day users should be the only things in that section, I think. `locked` _is_ at least on the search help page, which is linked at the bottom of that section.

Comment: @Kendra, so you're saying `locked` is too advanced for the Advanced Search Tips? ;-)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Exactly. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I view "Advanced Search Tips" more as "Intermediate Search Tips" really.

To explain, I feel that the extra search parameters there should be things people can figure out easily from using the site, terms that they'll see regularly as they go. Currently, that is what these "Advance Search Tips" are, and you can find what I would call the "Expert Search Tips" in the help page linked at the bottom of that section.

`locked` appears on that help page, and given how rare locks are compared to the number of questions that traverse the site daily, I think it's just something that doesn't need surfaced at the "Advanced Search Tips" level. Not enough users are going to know what it means or what it does.

If something is added to the "Advanced Search Tips" section, it should be something most users would understand the meaning of and be able to use easily, and not something with complex usage details. As Braiam mentioned in the comments, `code` is a good candidate for it, but even that isn't in this section.